# Как после переустановки приложения удалять все ключи?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно чтобы после переустановки(Удалить и заново установить) приложения удалялись все ключи (PlayerPrefs ).

Как я могу это реализовать?

Comment: Наверно, для такой ситуации было б лучше при старте игры/возврате фокуса/снятии с паузы считывать все данные из `PlayerPrefs` в какой-нибудь класс (н-р, `MySave`), очищать все поля в `PlayerPrefs`, а при выходе из приложения и/или потере фокуса - пройтись по полям класса `MySave` и сохранить все данные. Это поможет избежать накопление мусора в `PlayerPrefs`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Думаю, что в этом и была моя ошибка ,но переписывать весь код будет слишком трудно.Поэтому хочу узнать как удалить все PlayerPrefs после перезагрузки.

Comment: А если ориентироваться на версию приложения? И если в PlayerPrefs сохранена более ранняя версия (чем допустима) или поле пустое - производить очистку при запуске игры/приложения?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский А если версия не будет меняться , то что тогда ?

Comment: Тогда переписывать логику сохранения/загрузки. Зато теперь Вы получили бесценный опыт и осознали важность продумывания архитектуры игры.

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Оптимистично.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96212/discussion-between---and-veudd).

Comment: делается одной строкой кода https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll.html  при запуске приложения

Comment: @vmchar Нужно не при запуске , а после переустановки.

Comment: @Veudd тогда вызовите этот метод при первом запуске после установки. Разницы ноль

Comment: @vmchar Я могу запустить его только один раз после установки(В будущем не запускать)? Если да ,то как?

Comment: @Veudd из самого банального - добавьте какой-нибудь флаг в PlayerPrefs и проверьте по нему, надо ли вам чистить все ключи или нет